# store the data of the csv file into a 2d array

Tags: php, csv

suppose I have the following csv file called mycsv.csv

```
   "Date"      "order 1"   "order 2"   "order 3"          "total cost"
   01/04/2006   4 tires      1 oil       6 sparks plugs    "434.00$'
   03/08/2006   3 tires      2 oil       2 sparks plugs    "234.00$'
   03/12/2006   2 tires      0 oil       1 sparks plugs    "134.00$'
```

I want to know how to store the those  data in a 2d array, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You might use `fgetcsv`(see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). The difference to `str_getcsv` is that it takes a `File resource` as parameter and not a `String`.

You might also store each row in another Array to have a 2D Array e.g. (adjusted manual page example)

```
$twoDarray = array();
if (($handle = fopen("mycsv.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $twoDarray[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `str_getcsv` function: http://php.net/str_getcsv

```
$result = array();

$keys = array('Date', 'order 1', 'order 2', 'order 3', 'total cost');

foreach (file('mycsv.csv') as $key => $str)
{
    if ($key == 0)
        continue;   // skip first line

    $values = str_getcsv($str, "\t", '', '');

    $result[] = array_combine($keys, $values);
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I use [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) PHP native function to parse CSV data.

Answer (score 1):

Another quick way to do this:

```
$data = array_map(function($line) {
    return str_getcsv($line, ',');
}, file('data.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to archive this is using the [`fgetcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)-function.

Example (taken from the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and slightly altered):

```
if (($handle = fopen("mycsv.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned on comment from PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#114764)

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));
```